# Embedded vimeo/youtube videos not stopping

Tags: javascript, ipad, video, vimeo

I am here with a silly question. I am having a embedded vimeo player like this:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head><style type="text/css">body {background-color:black; color:black; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><iframe id="video" name="video" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67487897?byline=0&autoplay=1&api=1&player_id=video" width="768.000000" height="525.000000" frameborder="0"></body></html>";
```

and loaded it in a UIWebView like this:

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

The video loads fine but it does not autoplay. I, however, came to know that autoplay is not supported for embedded players. The code I used for autoplay is:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wbView{

            //            NSString *script = @"var message = 'api_play'; var vid = document.getElementById('video'); var window =  vid.contentWindow; window.postMessage('{\"event\":\"command\",\"func\":\"' + message + '\",\"args\":\"\"}', '*');";
            NSString *script = @"var vid = document.getElementById('video'); var window =  vid.contentWindow; window.postMessage('{\"method\":\"play\"}', vid.src.split('?')[0]);";
            NSLog(@"%@",script);
            [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
//the above portion did not work so I tried this one too but of no use...
                script = @"var vid = document.getElementById('video'); var window =  vid.contentWindow; window.api(\"play\"); alert('done'); vid.src = '';";
                [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
    }
```

But autoplay is not a major problem. The big problem here is that sometimes video does not stop when I get out of this screen. I tried multiple things and multiple scripts but the problem did not go the code I used is:

```
//        NSString *script = @"var message = 'api_unload'; var vid = document.getElementById('video'); var window =  vid.contentWindow; window.postMessage('{\"event\":\"command\",\"func\":\"' + message + '\",\"args\":\"\"}', '*'); vid.src = '';";
        NSString *script = @"var vid = document.getElementById('video'); var window =  vid.contentWindow; window.postMessage('{\"method\":\"pause\"}', vid.src.split('?')[0]);";
        NSLog(@"%@",script);
        [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

I also tried to use this:

```
NSString *script = @"var vid = document.getElementById('video'); var window =  vid.contentWindow; window.api(\"pause\"); vid.src = '';";
    NSLog(@"%@",script);
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

None worked.

Simply doing

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about://blank"]]];
```

does not work either. I face same problems with youtube videos too.

I am running out of options. Any person experienced same issues?

I am currently using iPad3 but I know the same thing happen on other ipads too.

Answer (score 0):

This will auto play an embed vimeo

```
http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=71788444&server=www.vimeo.com&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&color=&fullscreen=1&autoplay=1
```

Take note to the &autoplay=1 at the end